# Event controller not saving to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Hi I'm a student in ruby rails. I am trying to create something to save to my database. I can't get it to work.

Here is my form page:

```
<h1>Create your Event</h1>

<%= form_for @event do |f| %>

<div>
<%= f.label :name %>:
<%= f.text_field :name %><br />
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :description %>:
<%= f.text_field :description %><br />
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :location %>:
<%= f.text_field :location %><br />
</div>
<div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date%>
    <%= f.date_select :date,
        { order: [:month, :day, :year],
          prompt: [ day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' ]} %>
  </div>

<br>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new

  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      redirect_to event_index
    else
      render 'new'
      flash[:notice] = "Event not saved"
    end
```

When I click the create event button it doesn't do anything.

my schema

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "description"
t.date     "date"
t.string   "location"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

in the rails console I can see this:

> irb(main):001:0> Event.all
>     Event Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
>   => #
>   irb(main):002:0>

Comment: it would be a good idea to post your event_params in your controller, in case that is the source of the problem...

Comment: also, include a log for the action...

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

Use `@event.save!`. If the record cannot be created, the `!` will raise a helpful error.

And it doesn't look like you have your `event_params` defined in your controller.

Also, what does your Event model look like? Any validations?

Comment: My event model has no validations, I do have event_params defined in controller I just didn't show it in question.

Comment: Did you try the bang operator on save?

Comment: Where should i use that?

Comment: In your `create` action in the controller on the `if @event.save`.